# 響: what is N5116?

Tags: kanji, dictionary

I'm studying kanji and just got to this character recently. Kanji dictionaries all over the internet list "also N5116" as one of its meanings but what exactly is that N5116? I tried googling it a bit but only found the same dictionaries.

Comment: Maybe the 116th character in a list of kanji for the JLPT N5? Otherwise, I have no idea what this would mean.

Comment: @Pleiades I thought that JLPT stopped using kanji lists when they switched to the new system N1–N5 (from 1–4).

Comment: @Earthliŋ I never knew the old system (I'm too young and too new to the language to have) so I wasn't aware that they stopped the numbering of kanji. I'm still able to find lists that do so, so I assumed it was from one of those more unofficial ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned by Earthliŋ, these are indices in the Classic Nelson kanji dictionary. A [quick search](http://rut.org/cgi-bin/j-e/jis/nocolor/dokanji?index=t&ivalue=3a39%7C3641&) tells us that N5114 corresponds to the index N6610 in the *New Nelson* dictionary. Here's an image from my New Nelson dictionary. N5116 presumably corresponds to N6612 then.

[image: N5114 N5116]

When I look for pages that mention this, it looks like they're using outdated versions of [kanjidic](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/kanjidic.html)...

Answer (score 6):

I think that N5116 is a dictionary index for the "Classic Nelson", i.e. *The Original Modern Reader's Japanese–English Character Dictionary: Classic Edition* by Andrew Nelson, so that N5116 means "character 5116 in the Classic Nelson".

The actual *kanji* 響 [seems to be 5114 in this dictionary](http://jisho.org/search/%E9%9F%BF%20%23kanji) (i.e. N5114 in the notation used above) and I'm guessing that N5116 is a variant of the same character. Unfortunately, I don't have a copy of the Classic Nelson to check what variant that would be...

In any case, I think "also N5116" is an annotation to the *kanji* 響, meaning that 響 can also be written in some other way, and somewhere during database crunching got listed as a meaning, which it is not.